# Why on Codeigniter 4 the REST outoput is not encoded?

Tags: rest, codeigniter, encoding, codeigniter-4

I am using Codeigniter 4 to create a REST API. On my "production" environment, the response is returned as expected, but on my localhost it returns characters that are not encoded (or wrongly encoded):

```
API Service: /api/are_you/alive
Expected:
  "timeout": "2023\/02\/19 21:01:27",
  "payload": "yes"

Got:
 ���������������� (so many of these)
 "timeout":"2023\/02\/19 20:58:40",
 "payload":"yes"
```

The send response function is:

```
 protected function send_response($response, $error = 0)
 {
      echo json_encode($output);
      die();
 }
```

And headers are set on the class constructor:

```
 header('Content-Type: application/json');
 header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-API-KEY, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Access-Control-Request-Method");
 header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST");
```

The same commit running in both environments.

What am I missing on my localhost?

Comment: Please, share the actual source code. Currently, `$output` is undefined. Without a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), it's almost impossible to be of assistance.

Comment: Maybe you could check the default character sets on your both web servers? You could also try to force them with headers… but first of all check them at your client level (inspect mode in your browser then network tab).